# How to make Nginx proxy pass work with external requests to nodes

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Below is what I want to achieve;

- Forward traffic from `http://myip.com` to  `http://localhost:8081`
- Forward traffic from `http://gitlab.myip.com` to  `http://localhost:8443`

The following snippet is the content of my Nginx configuration file;

```sh
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/two-applications.conf

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myip.com;

  location / {
    # Proxy pass to Apache server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name gitlab.myip.com;

  location / {
    # Proxy pass to GitLab server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
  }
}
```

It works as expected within my network but hangs when accessed from outside my network except when port `8081` and `8443` are appended to `http://myip.com` and `http://gitlab.myip.com` respectively.

My router is forwarding traffic from ports `80`, `8443`, `8081` to the computer hosting these applications and my firewall was disabled by running `ufw disable`.

This is my (abbreviated) output from running sudo netstat -tulpn:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20603/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13513/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      685/apache2
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**
The problem here was with the ISP blocking port 80

Comment: Thanks for the edits. When accessing from my browser, the website hangs. So 'fails' would be that I can't access the website from the browser (or wget).

Comment: So the connection attempt times out, rather than being rejected outright, or returning an error status? That smells to be like you have firewall issues, either on your machine or on your router

Comment: I belive so. Wget times out, if that helps. And the browser keeps spinning for a long time, where nothing happens. But I can't think of why the firewall or router would be the issue when it works when the ports are appended.

Comment: That suggests your firewall or router is configured differently for port 80 vs port 8443/8081.

Comment: Port forwarding is enabled for ports 80, 8081, 8443. And ufw disable was run on my ubuntu pc.

Comment: Perhaps your ISP is blocking port 80, then? It doesn't look like your nginx config since it's listening on 0.0.0.0, so it's probably in one of the other moving parts which we can't see.

Comment: That's a good point. I wonder if they have something to do with it.. https://www.cox.com/residential/support/internet-ports-blocked-or-restricted-by-cox.html This link makes me think that you're right (since I'm using cox ISP).

Comment: Looks like port 443 is open -- why not serve over HTTPS instead? You can use a self-signed certificate pretty easily (or use LetsEncrypt if you want something a bit better), and that has the added benefit of encrypting all traffic to your server

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like a good plan. My new config uses 'listen 443' instead of 80 (with 443 being port forwarded), but I can't access the site for some reason. I think it's because I don't have the certs, or something of that nature. Not sure where to store the LetsEncrypt either.

Comment: @Michael : Is `myip.com` registered with a domain name registrar or just a placeholder for your IP?

Comment: Yes myip.com is a domain name registered with a registrar